# Asymptotics for solutions of a version of Lienard's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

Consider the second order differential equation
$ x'' + f(x)x' + g(x) = 0 $ with 
$$
f(x) = -\lambda + x^2, \quad g(x) = (-1 + x^2)x \, .
$$
with $\lambda > 0$.

*Note: The original post had a misprint in this formula. $g$ should be a cubic, not a quadratic.*

This has the general form of [Lienard's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard_equation). Much is known about the asymptotic behavior (as $t \to \infty$) of solutions, if $g(x) = (1 + x^2)x$. Essentially, all non-constant solutions must either lie on a limit cycle (which is unique) or converge to this limit cycle.

However, in the form given above, there are stationary points at $x = \pm 1$ that are stable if $\lambda < 1$, there is a Hopf bifurcation as $\lambda$ increases past $1$, and numerical evidence suggests that there are unstable limit cycles coexisting with stable large amplitude limit cycles for some $\lambda < 1$. An image of the stable limit cycle for $\lambda = .772$ is shown below. So the picture is more complicated.

Is anything known about the global behavior of solutions for this type of problem?

[image: Limit cycle for $\lambda = .771]

Comment: I assume that the large amplitude limit cycles exist for $\lambda > 1$, instead of $\lambda < 1$?

Comment: No, that is not a misprint. See my edited post with an image of a limit cycle for $\lambda < 1$.